# bbfreeze and protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to package a script with bbfreeze that uses the protocol buffers. Using bbfreeze like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bbfreeze import Freezer
import os

f = Freezer('dist')
f.addScript('main.py')

f()
```

Results in `No module named google.protbuf` on the client. Reading the docs a bit, I try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bbfreeze import Freezer
import os

f = Freezer('dist',includes=["google.protobuf"])
f.addScript('main.py')

f()
```

Results in `ImportError: No module named google` when running the bbfreeze script.

bbfreeze is at version 0.97.3 installed from `easy_install`. Anyone run into this issue or a similar one previously?

Comment: Sounds like you have not installed protobuf... try "pip install protobuf" to install it from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf .

Comment: @SpikeGronim, you want to make that an answer? I forgot to install protobuf into the chroot I'm using to package this software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have not installed protobuf... try "pip install protobuf" to install it from pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf .